# how to show text clock in TextView?

Tags: java, android

**In this code I use a linear layout to show TextClock. Now I want to use TextView to show this clock. How can I do that? The problem is:**

```
linear2.addView(clock);
```

**How can i change it to TextView?**

```
    TextClock clock = new TextClock(this);
clock.setTextSize(50);
clock.setTextColor(Color.RED);
clock.setFormat24Hour("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss cccc");
linear2.addView(clock);
```